# Rust GTK Hello World Example

Tags: rust, gtk

I'm trying to follow along with [this](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk3-rs/stable/latest/docs/gtk/index.html) hello world application with gtk and Rust

```
use gtk::prelude::*;
use gtk::{Application, ApplicationWindow};

fn main() {
    let app = Application::builder()
        .application_id("org.example.HelloWorld")
        .build();

    app.connect_activate(|app| {
        // We create the main window.
        let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
            .application(app)
            .default_width(320)
            .default_height(200)
            .title("Hello, World!")
            .build();

        // Don't forget to make all widgets visible.
        win.show_all();
    });

    app.run();
}
```

I am having some trouble getting the example to compile, the compile errors I get are

```
error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `builder` found for struct `Application` in the current scope
 --> src/main.rs:5:28
  |
5 |     let app = Application::builder()
  |                            ^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `Application`

error[E0599]: no function or associated item named `builder` found for struct `ApplicationWindow` in the current scope
  --> src/main.rs:11:38
   |
11 |         let win = ApplicationWindow::builder()
   |                                      ^^^^^^^ function or associated item not found in `ApplicationWindow`
```

Here is my Cargo.toml file -

```
[package]
name = "color-picker"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
chrono = "0.4"
futures = "0.3"
atk = "^0"
glib-sys = "^0"
gobject-sys = "^0"
glib = "^0"
gio = "^0"
gdk = "^0"
gdk-pixbuf = "^0"
gtk = "^0"
once_cell = "^0"
pango = "^0"
pangocairo = "^0"
cascade = "^0"
cairo-rs = { version = "^0", features = ["png"] }


[features]
#default = ["gtk_3_22_30"]
gtk_3_18 = ["gtk/v3_18", "gdk-pixbuf/v2_32", "gdk/v3_18", "gio/v2_46", "glib/v2_46", "pango/v1_38"] #for CI tools
gtk_3_22_30 = ["gtk_3_18", "gtk/v3_22_30", "gdk-pixbuf/v2_36", "gdk/v3_22", "gio/v2_56", "glib/v2_56", "pango/v1_42"] #for CI tools
gtk_3_24 = ["gtk_3_22_30", "gtk/v3_24", "atk/v2_30", "gdk-pixbuf/v2_36_8", "gdk/v3_24", "gio/v2_58", "glib/v2_58"] #for CI tools
```

Am I missing something in order to get this to compile?

Thanks!

#### Edit: Fixed Cargo.toml file

Comment: Pretty sure your Cargo.toml file shouldn't look like what you've posted here. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Cargo.toml` is still incorrect after the edit.

It most likely should look like this instead:

```
[package]
name = "color-picker"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
gtk = "0.14.0"
```

referencing the `gtk` crate from [crates.io](https://crates.io/crates/gtk).